# Show custom post type category posts on the footer

Tags: php, wordpress

Can you please guide me how to show certain category posts on the footer. I am using custom post type news-site, taxonomy is news-category.

The link structure is abc.com/news-category/politics-news. The Politics news is a category page and all politics related news showing on the category page.

I don't know how to show 5 recent posts with same category on the footer.

I have tried with tag_id but nothing is showing.

Also i have tried this related post [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616891/trying-to-show-custom-post-type-specific-custom-category-posts) but didn't work

Can you please guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the 5 posts of custom taxonomy by using the following logic.

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    $term_id = esc_html( $categories[0]->term_id );   
}
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news-site',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'news-category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $term_id
            )
        )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
         echo get_the_title(); 
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Don't forget to pass `taxonomy_name` in the query

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. What is taxonomy_name  politics-news ?

Comment: Nope , you can find it by visiting that URL , like : /wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category.

In your case go to that custom category and you can find it.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, 

I have changed the taxonomy with news-category also changed post_type =>'new-site' , nothing happen

Comment: I think you mentioned it above : news-category , copy this to taxonomy

Comment: check $term_id by echo. If this is empty that you can not get posts. Also have you echo get_the_title(); in loop? I edited the answer.

Comment: Where i echo the $term_id ? also i have tried echo get_the_title(); still not showing anything

Comment: edit the line $term_id = $queried_object->term_id; to echo $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

Comment: Try this if you don't get term_id, $categories = get_the_category();
 
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    $term_id = esc_html( $categories[0]->term_id );   
}

Comment: here is the link /wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=news-category&tag_ID=57&post_type=news-site&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dnews-category%26post_type%3Dnews-site